# Revoke and Remove all Google tokens/permissions in Electron App Logout

Tags: javascript, google-api, electron, google-oauth, chromium

I have created an app with Electron that allows users to sign-in and sign-out.
On logout, I delete all information stored in `keytar` (access tokens, etc.)
I then call `oAuth2Client.revokeCredentials()` when logging out.

```
const { google, GoogleApis } = require('googleapis')

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    credentials.client_id,
    credentials.client_secret,
    credentials.redirect_uris[1]
)

async function logout() {
    console.log('Logging out....')
    await keytar.deletePassword(keytarService, keytarAccount)

    await oAuth2Client.revokeCredentials()
}
```

However, when the user opens the app again, and they get the login screen, their Google Account is still there where all they have to do is click on it. They don't have to login again, they don't have to enter a password, and they don't have to use 2FA again.

What I am looking for is, when a user logs out of my Desktop Application, they are completely Logged out with no Google remnants left behind, such that, when they open the Application the next time, they have to re-enter a user name and a password and use their 2FA.

Comment: did you find any solution for this. I'm facing the similar issue, where `revokeCredentials` doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind the users seeing their google account logged in, is that the users didn't logout of their google account, so all the session cookies are stored in your renderer and revoking the tokens in your main process will not revoke the tokens in your renderer process. In order to clear the users session data from your renderer, what you can do is that, you can clear the storage from that renderer as shown below.

```
// Before quitting the window, clear the storage so all the cookies related to google are cleared 

AuthWindow.webContents.session.clearStorageData().then(function (data) {
        AuthWindow.destroy();
});
```

Next time when the users opens their app again, they will need to login their account using their credentials as all the session data related to their account is cleared now.